# Can I ask here for a blog post about programming review?

Tags: discussion

Can I ask here for a blog post about programming review? (I'm totally new to Code Review)

Comment: I think you should not have been down voted for this... You were asking about what is acceptable in the community. You didn't just come out and ask for the blog post.

Answer (score 7):

## No.

First place to check is in the [[help/on-topic]](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page:

> Code Review Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for seeking peer review of your code. We're working together to improve the skills of programmers worldwide by taking working code and making it better.
>
> If you are **looking for feedback on a specific working piece of code from your project** in the following areas…
>
> - Best practices and design pattern usage
> - Security issues
> - Performance
> - Correctness in unanticipated cases
>
> then you are in the right place!
>
> However, **if your question is not about a particular piece of code** and instead is a generally applicable question about…
>
> - Best practices in general (that is, it's okay to ask "Does this code follow common best practices?", but not "What is the best practice regarding X?")
> - Tools, improving, or conducting code reviews
> - How to add a feature to or solve a problem with your code
> - Trouble-shooting, debugging, or understanding code snippets
> - Higher-level architecture and design of software systems
>
> then your question is **off-topic** for this site.